# How should i go about using a user input in an equation like Fahrenheit to Celsius? When I run the code it says it is the conversion line

Tags: python

```
#taking temperature in fahrenheit
fahrenheit = float(input("Enter temperature degrees in fahrenheit:"))

#Coversion formula
conv_for = (input - 32) * 5/9

#calculation for celcius
celcius = conv_for
    print("%02f degrees in fahrenheit is equal to %02f degrees in celcius")
```

I am fairly new to coding so are their any other ways to improve this?

Comment: You have an extra indent.

Comment: It is generally a good idea to include the full error message so people can see what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

In this line, you're taking the temperature the user enters and storing it in a variable called `fahrenheit`.

```
#taking temperature in fahrenheit
fahrenheit = float(input("Enter temperature degrees in fahrenheit:"))
```

So if the user typed in, say, `76`, then `fahrenheit` would store the value `76`. In this line, however, you're using `input` instead of `fahrenheit`.

```
#Coversion formula
conv_for = (input - 32) * 5/9
```

`input` is essentially a function that takes what the user types in and stores it. I think what you're actually wanting is, instead of `input`, to use `fahrenheit`. While we're at it, let's assign that to `celsius` instead of `conv_for` for clarity. Here's the corrected version of the above:

```
celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9
```

Similarly, your print statement needs to specify which variables go in for each spot:

```
print(f"{fahrenheit} degrees in fahrenheit is equal to {celsius} degrees in celsius")
```

You could alternatively do it like you were doing before and it will then round at 2 decimal places (that is what `02` means):

```
print("%.02f degrees in fahrenheit is equal to %.02f degrees in celsius" % (fahrenheit, celsius))
```

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you so much. What is the difference between using f"{fahrenheit}..." and using %02f?

Comment: You're welcome! Good question—I've updated my answer to reflect that—the way I did it with `f` is a newer feature of Python which is a little cleaner, but I added to my answer how you can do it the way you were intending (which also has the advantage of taking the result and rounding to 2 decimal places, so a number like 33.259 would just become 33.26). If you don't care about the rounding, you can use them interchangably.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code:

```
fahrenheit = float(input("Enter temperature degrees in fahrenheit:"))

#Coversion formula
conv_for = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9

#calculation for celcius
celcius = conv_for
print(f"{fahrenheit} degrees in fahrenheit is equal to {celcius} degrees in celcius")
```

Answer (score 0):

ok first thing indention is important in python so be careful,

```
# Taking temperature in fahrenheit
fahrenheit = float(input("Enter temperature degrees in fahrenheit:"))

# Calculation for celcius
celcius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9

#Displaying the output
print("%s degrees in fahrenheit is equal to %s degrees in celcius"%(fahrenheit, celcius))
```